# Fit mat-card into mat-grid-list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm building an Angular web page with a grid of cards. To do that I'm using `mat-grid-list` with many `mat-grid-tile` components inside. Inside every tile there's a `mat-card`.

Here a minimal example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdeuhs?file=app/app.component.html)

I would like that every card fills precisely its own parent tile.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this in css:

```
mat-card {
  border: 4px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%-5;
}
```

to this:

```
mat-card {
  border: 4px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
}
```

In css if you want to make math operations you use calc() function.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `height: 100%` to the `mat-card`:

```css
mat-card {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8xsjs8?file=app/app.component.css)